# BigQuery GROUP BY function still showing duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates, google-bigquery

I'm doing a query in BigQuery:

```
SELECT id FROM [table] WHERE  city = 'New York City' GROUP BY id
```

The weird part is it shows duplicate ids, often right next to each other. 
There is absolutely nothing different between the ids themselves. There are around 3 million rows total, for ~500k IDs. So there are a lot of duplicates, but that is by design. We figured the filtering would easily eliminate that but noticed discrepancies in totals.

Is there a reason BigQuery's `GROUP BY` function would work improperly? For what its worth, the dataset has ~3 million rows.

Example of duplicate ID:

```
56abdb5b9a75d90003001df6
56abdb5b9a75d90003001df6
```

Comment: can you copy and paste some ids here?

Comment: 56abdb5b9a75d90003001df6

Comment: So you have a column named id and there are 3 million rows in it but when you group by the only column in the select statement you get duplicates? That doesn't add up. There is something else going on here. What is the datatype of id? Is this part of another query?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show a self-contained example that exhibits the problem. It's generally easier to do this using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) since legacy SQL doesn't support `WITH` clauses or a proper `UNION ALL`.

Comment: There are 2.98 million rows. Each row has 30+ columns. I'm trying to find how many unique IDs are in any given "area" which is a county. When I do that for super large areas, like USA or New York State, the numbers are 10k off from my source of truth. I then chose really small areas and saw that there were IDs listed twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the only explanation is your id is STRING and in reality those two ids are different because of spaces before or most likely after what is "visible" for eyes

I recommend you to adjust your query like below

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(id, ' ', '') 
FROM [table] 
WHERE city = 'New York City' 
GROUP BY 1
```

another option to troubleshoot would be below

```sql
SELECT id, LENGTH(id)
FROM [table] 
WHERE city = 'New York City' 
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

so you can see if those ids are same by length or not  - my initial assumption was about space  - but it can be any other char(s) including non printable

Comment: When I read this I thought you were for sure right, but I ran this query and still ended up with the same number of duplicates. The IDs are indeed strings though..

Comment: EMOTICONS! It was an emoticon! The symbols weren't showing up but when I went back to the original document I found them. Thanks!